# Which fields to be used in Series, Values and Category in ssrs chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

Hi i am newbie to ssrs report, and i have no idea which fields to be used in Series , values and category to create a chart like shown in diagram

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of hard to answer since I don't know what the fields are called in your datasets. In the image you posted however...Columns B-E are Category Groups, the Integers in B2 - E3 are the values and March / April are the Series.

Hope that's enough for you to figure this out.